# How to get data out of QuerySnapshot in Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

This question has been asked many times before but not in Android Java. I've gone through the firestore docs , it uses a for loop to get the data. In my case , I need a single field from my query (I know my query will return only one document).

Here is the query:

```
db.collection("songs").whereEqualTo("email",userauth.getEmail()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                QuerySnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
                if (!snapshot.isEmpty()) {
             //Display the data this is where I'm facing issue
}
}
```

I want to display a single field `link` in my data.
I tried this:

```
DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    userinfo.setText(document.get("link"));
```

But there are some errors. There are so many different snapshots I've no idea what does what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is query snapshot always returns a list , in my case it will be a list with only one object.

So:

```
DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.getDocuments().get(0);
                    userinfo.setText((String)document.get("link"));
```